# Travis uses Firefox 56 although Firefox 59 is installed on same system

Tags: php, selenium, firefox, travis-ci, geckodriver

When running Selenium on Travis, it uses Firefox version 56. I need to use the latest version of Firefox, 59. Running `apt-get update` and `upgrade` does not solve this problem, but instead leaves the system with two different versions of Firefox, both 56 and 59.

```
$ which firefox
/usr/local/bin/firefox
$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 56.0.2
```

but

```
$ /usr/bin/firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 59.0.2
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this so that Firefox 59 is the only version available on the system?

One temporary fix could be just to copy over the 56 bin file with the 59 one.

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_?

Comment: @DebanjanB Sorry, this is PHP.

Comment: Doesn't matters, the core implementation through _Selenium_ remains the same. Only the command syntax differs within different binding arts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Java perspective

Even though you are having multiple installations of different versions of **Firefox Binary** you can still pick up your choice of the desired *Firefox Binary* version through the [**`setBinary()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#setBinary-org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary-) option of [**FirefoxOptions()**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html) Class during your test execution as follows :

```
System.setProperty("god.bless.us", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```